# Implementing Fragment to Activity communication without implementing interfaces directly in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I have a main activity that is responsible for switching between different fragments. These fragments have interfaces that the activity needs to implement in order for the fragment to send data back to the activity.

At the moment I cast the context of `onAttach` method in the fragment to an instance of a specific interface specified in the fragment. However, as the activity class has to implement all these for the casting to work, the methods specified in the interfaces also need to be implemented directly in the class.

What I'd like to do instead is to create an instance of these interfaces and save these into class variables. The problem is how can I pass the reference to the fragment? The process should be as generic as possible for easy fragment additions.

So instead of the traditional way

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragmentListener {
    public void myFragmentMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

what I'd like is

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyFragmentListener myFragmentListener = new MyFragmentListener() {
        public void myFragmentMethod() {
            // ...
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is how to inform the fragment about the interface implementation. Using a BroadcastReceiver would work but seems a bit messy.

Comment: Try Eventbus. Its much more cleaner

Comment: @RissmonSuresh Seems nice but this won't solve the problem of decoupling the methods from the class root.

Answer (score 0):

> EventBus

Is not a dirty thing ☺️
Try it and you'll become addicted soon... 
It's dedicated exactly for situations like yours and its super simple to use. 
You define a class, you can add parameters, methods and so on... And you just populate the event required (with class name) and the sky is the limit from here. 
[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

You'll see the description there

Answer (score 0):

Have a setter method for the Listener in the Fragment. And call that setter method from Activity, after creating the Fragment.

Comment: This doesn't make it very generic. Currently I instantiate the fragments from  the class name by calling `Class.forName(...).newInstance()`. I'd have to dynamically cast these to a specific fragment and then call a method. This gets quite complicated and I'm not sure if it would even work: as the interfaces aren't the same for each one, I'd still have to do checking one by one.

Answer (score 0):

There's really only two ways to "cleanly" hook a fragment and activity together for the purposes of communication: `Fragment.onAttach()` and `Activity.onAttachFragment()`.

The standard pattern is something like this (in your fragment):

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    callbacks = (MyInterface) context;
}
```

You say you don't want to do this. That's a little odd, but ok. You could perhaps try a slightly different approach:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) context;
    callbacks = activity.getCallbacks();
}
```

This is slightly awkward because you'd have to expose a getter for each type of callback interface among your various fragments, but it ought to work

You can also try to approach it from the activity's perspective:

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    if (fragment instanceof FragmentTypeOne) {
        ((FragmentTypeOne) fragment).setCallbacks(callbacksOne);
    } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentTypeTwo) {
        ((FragmentTypeTwo) fragment).setCallbacks(callbacksTwo);
    } // ...
}
```

This is also slightly awkward, since you have to repeatedly call `instanceof` to know which field to pass to the fragment.

Still, I hope this helps.

### Edit

Another idea I just thought of is to implement the interfaces in your activity but then simply forward the calls to your helpers. This might not meet your requirements since it still involves having your activity implement all the various interfaces, but it should let you create separate classes to implement the actual behavior, and your activity will just look like this:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragmentListener {
    public void myFragmentMethod() {
        helper.myFragmentMethod();
    }
}
```